# Cosmos DB vs DynamoDB comparison

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to have performance testing on Cosmodb against dynamodb.Currently I am designing a sloution in cloud where we need to have sub second response time Need to have apple to apple comparison.

Comment: This type of question is off-topic for StackOverflow. You'll need to do your own benchmarking. You're talking about two completely different services, on two different clouds. There's no possible way of providing an objective answer here - you'll only get opinion and discussion.

Comment: Please review [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to write a good question

Comment: yes , there are lots of comparison like this . But I didnt find a comparison between these 2 databases.I know there will be in partiality in showing the results but it will give you an early idea.For eg,arangodb.com/2015/10/benchmark-postgresql-mongodb-arangod‌​b

Answer (score -2):

Only you and you alone can do the perf testing of your use case. How would anyone else do the apple-to-apple comparison on two general-purpose databases and still satisfy your scenario requirements?

Comment: yes , there are lots of comparison like this . But I didnt find a comparison between these 2 databases.I know there will be in partiality in showing the results but it will give you an early idea.For eg,https://www.arangodb.com/2015/10/benchmark-postgresql-mongodb-arangodb/

Comment: I don't think this is a good example and not what you want anyway. This is a comparison that is done by a database vendor for the use cases where that database really shines. It's missing the other 99% of use cases and it's much more likely your use case is among these 99%.